# Add item to arraylist if it does not already exist in list

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a listview showing an arraylist, when an item is clicked it is added to another arraylist and displayed in another activity. What is my problem? I want that if an item (eg a dog) I touch once, is added to the second activity, and it shows. But if I were to touch the item (dog) is not added again.

We would say that I want to check if it exists, not add.

I've tried so, but without success.

```
if (page2 == null)
{
    page2 = (ListView) LayoutInflater.from(Local_mostrar_bebidaActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.page_two_viewpager_listview, null);
    page2.setAdapter(adapterlistvMenuVINOSespumosos);
    page2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            if (MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.contains( position)){}
            else
                MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.add(itemsListVMenuVINOSespumosos.get(position));

        }});
    }
    page = page2;
    break;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have:

```
if (MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.contains( position)){}
    else
MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.add(itemsListVMenuVINOSespumosos.get(position));
```

You are checking if `itemsListVMiPedido` contains the integer, `position`, but you are adding `itemsListVMenuVINOSespumosos.get(position)` to the list. You need to check if the list contains them *item*, not the index (think of it exactly like what you are trying to do: "do not add item to list if list already contains *item*). You probably mean something like this (I just made up `Item` for example, use whatever class your objects are):

```
Item item = itemsListVMenuVINOSespumosos.get(position);
if (MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.contains(item)) { // <- look for item!
   // ... item already in list
} else {
   MiPedidoActivity.itemsListVMiPedido.add(item);
}
```

By the way, as a suggestion, if your item classes have `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly implemented, consider a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (which will preserve insertion order but will not allow duplicates). There are other [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementations that may be useful too  (e.g. `TreeSet` if your items implement `Comparable`), depending on your ordering/sorting requirements.